Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.resolveComponent is not a function
I make an input to add data on my dashboard, the data store is correct, but in the console view I saw an error that mentions resolveComponent. But there's no function called resolveComponent in my code, so I clicked and I saw this error inside the router.ts file, so I checked that file, but I didn't see such a file inside my node_modules. I used React and Laravel. Please help me fix this issue. Because of this issue, I couldn't display a flash message. Thanks in advance.
Here is my dashboard code:
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";

export default function Dashboard(props) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [harga, setHarga] = useState("");
    const [isNotif, setIsNotif] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const data = {
            title,
            description,
            harga,
        };
        Inertia.post("/rumah", data);
        setIsNotif(true);
        setTitle(""), setDescription(""), setHarga("");
    };

    console.log("baru: ", props);

    return (
        <AuthenticatedLayout
            header={
                <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold leading-tight text-gray-800">
                    Dashboard
                </h2>
            }
        >
            <Head title="Dashboard" />

            <div className="py-12">
                <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div className="overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                        <div className="p-6 bg-white text-gray-900">
                            You're logged in now! <br /> <br />
                            <div className="drawer">
                                <input
                                    id="my-drawer"
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    className="drawer-toggle"
                                />
                                <div className="drawer-content">
                                    {/* Page content here */}
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor="my-drawer"
                                        className="btn btn-primary drawer-button"
                                    >
                                        Input Data Rumah
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="drawer-side">
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor="my-drawer"
                                        aria-label="close sidebar"
                                        className="drawer-overlay"
                                    ></label>
                                    <ul className="menu bg-base-200 text-base-content min-h-full w-80 p-4"> <br />
                                        <div className="items-center text-white align-top text-center">
                                            <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">
                                                BUAT DATA RUMAH BARU
                                            </h2>
                                        </div><br /><br />
                                        {/* Sidebar content here */}
                                        <li>
                                        <div>{isNotif && props.flash.pesan} </div>
                                            <label>Title</label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                className="input input-bordered m-0 w-full bg-white"
                                                onChange={(title) =>
                                                    setTitle(title.target.value)
                                                }
                                                value={title}
                                            />
                                            <label>Description</label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                className="input input-bordered m-0 w-full bg-white"
                                                onChange={(description) =>
                                                    setDescription(
                                                        description.target.value
                                                    )
                                                }
                                                value={description}
                                            />
                                            <label>Price</label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                className="input input-bordered m-0 mb-4 w-full bg-white"
                                                onChange={(harga) =>
                                                    setHarga(harga.target.value)
                                                }
                                                value={harga}
                                            />
                                            <button
                                                className="btn btn-primary m-2"
                                                onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
                                            >
                                                Submit
                                            </button>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>{/* <a>Sidebar Item 2</a> */}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div className="p-6 bg-white text-gray-900">

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </AuthenticatedLayout>
    );
}

I have tried to ask AI but didnt get the proper answer

The error is clear... you are trying to instantiate a component and the resolving function is failing (with a weird error). Check on your stacktrace which part of the file is triggering that error. You are saying it is router.ts, which line? What is it trying to do exactly at that line?
